# How to set multiple initial jobs on Jenkins Pipeline View

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, continuous-deployment

I am using Jenkins to manage build workflow. I have three projects `ui`, `backend` and `release`. The `release` project needs to be triggered either by `ui` and `backend`. In other words, `ui` and `backend` are upstream projects while `release` is the downstream project. I want to show them in Jenkins Pipeline view. But I can only select one project as the initial job. See below screenshot.

[image]

I know I can setup two pipeline views one for `ui -> release` the other is for `backend -> release` but I am looking for a better solution.
How can I select multiple initial jobs in the Pipeline view?

Comment: Similar problem, did you found a way around ?

Comment: Unfortunately jenkins doesn't support such requirement. What I did is to create an initial project and make it as upstream project for other projects. In this way, I can trigger this initial project in order to trigger the whole pipeline job.